# Limit the number of features rendered in a map

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, expression, rendering

I have a layer of village points and I want to limit the number of features rendered to a maximum of 50 points. I tried using `Layer Properties > Labels > Rendering > Limit number of features to be labeled to` 50. But this obviously limits only the labels, and not the points themselves, like in the image below:

[image]

I also tried `Layer Properties > Style > Control feature rendering order` but it does not seem to do anything about the limiting of the points rendered in the map. How can I limit the number of features to be rendered, preferably using an expression/the Field calculator (so that I can dynamically set the same for other similar layers)?

I am using QGIS 2.18.

Comment: Based on what criteria should features be filtered? Randomly?

Comment: It could be chosen randomly, but I would also prefer the 50 villages with the highest population are shown. The layer has a column 'population' if that helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**QGIS 3.x:**

You can use the feature filter in `layer properties` -> `source` -> `query builder`:

[image]

E.g. use `$id  < 51` as expression to only show the first 50 features. Or use `"population" > x` to display only vilages with a population greater than `x`.

---

**QGIS 2.x:**

In QGIS 2.18 you can find the same menu in `layer properties` -> `general` -> `query builder`:

[image]

Comment: How can I do this in QGIS 2.18? I could not find "Source" in the Layer properties.